# How to read Dynamic files in Cypress

Tags: cypress

While doing automation I have to download files and store them in Cypress folder. File downloading and storing works, but I am not sure how to read those files since every time it is downloading its Prefix with some random number.

**For Example**

in the `cypress`/`Animesh` folder I can see some random files like `1234_abc.json`, `2345_abc.json`, `3334_abc.json`, `3454_abc.json`

How do I read the first file?

Comment: Use regex for get file downloaded ? Without taking into account prefix

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue. I can successfully download the file but my issue is I cannot find a way to soft wait for it to be ready. I'm looking for something to check that there is at least one file in the folder. I'm using the findFile task but the issue is it doesn't wait, and i'm not sure how to get it to wait?

```html
    findFile: (mask) => {
      if (!mask)
        throw new Error('Missing a file mask to seach');
      return globby(mask).then((list) => {
        if (!list.length)
          throw new Error(`Could not find files matching mask "${mask}"`);
        return list[0];
      });
    }
  });
```